# Android AWS s3 CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, amazon-s3, androidhttpclient, amazon-cognito

I am trying to upload/download/list file at aws bucket.

I wrote following code in my fragment for setting up credentials it throws NoSuchMethodErrorException at line (mActivity.getApplicationContext)

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(

               mActivity.getApplicationContext(),   // using in fragments
               "ap-XXXX-X:0XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXb4", // Identity Pool ID
               Regions.AP_XXXX_X // Region
       );

AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider) ;
```

The following error it throws :

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method (Lcom/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration;Lcom/amazonaws/http/HttpClient;)V in class Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceClient; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient' appears in /data/app/com.hs.userportal-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes6.dex)

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    dexOptions {

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "XXX.XX.XXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 30
        versionName "4.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                appendVersionName(variant, defaultConfig)
            }
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {

        cruncherEnabled = false
    }

    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/classes.jar'
        exclude '...'
    }

}
def appendVersionName(variant, defaultConfig) {

    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        if (output.zipAlign) {
            def file = output.outputFile
            def fileName = file.name.replace("app-release.apk", "HealthScion- " + defaultConfig.versionName + "v.apk")
            output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
        }

        def file = output.packageApplication.outputFile
        def fileName = file.name.replace("app-release.apk", "HealthScion- " + defaultConfig.versionName + "v.apk")
        output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.4.4'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.4.4'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.4.4'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.4.4'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-kms:2.4.4'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.4.4'
    compile 'dev.dworks.libs:astickyheader:0.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
    compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.5.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/xmlworker-5.5.6.jar')
    compile project(':SlidingMenuLibrary')
    compile project(':ViewPagerIndicatorlibrary')
    compile project(':swipelistview')
    compile project(':demo_cloud_tagview')
    compile project(':SegmentedControlLibrary')
    compile project(':Simpl3r')
    compile project(':MPChartLib')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:audiovideo:1.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I also created new project and integrated aws s3 code with same CognitoCredentialsProvider, it works perfectly.

Therefore, apparently issue must reside in my gradle file.

Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

I was using 3rd party library "Simpl3r"  which uploads file to my bucket. Since i inserted this library quiet some time ago, so the aws-sdk-s3 version it was using was outdated.

Solution which works for me:

1. open simpler gradle file.

   removed line: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

   added line : compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.4.4'
2. update aws sdk ver over there i.e 2.4.4 (latest at the moment)
3. integrated aws sdk ver 2.4.4 (similar with Simpl3r library version) in    build.gradle(app), to use this aws library function throughout my app module .

Atlast, my duplicate entry of classes.class (which builds at run time) issue gets resolved.

Tip: Try to make version of your sub-module(gradle files) similar to app gradle file.
Also, make sure that you use compile fileTree(dir:'libs', include: ['*jar']) in sub module gradle file only if , any particular jar file needs to be run with that particular module .